# converting to double to two decimal places

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

Hi i am a c# novice would someone politely tell me how to convert the values of this piece of code to a double/rounded decimal.. thanks in advance

```
DataTable dtValues = new DataTable("GetValues");

strValueNumber = ValueNumber[0].ToString();
dtGetValues = SQLMethods.GetValues(strValueNumber);

total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dtValues.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    total1 = total1 + Convert.ToInt32(dtGetValues.Rows[i]["total_1"]);                  
    total2 = total2 + Convert.ToDouble(dtGetValues.Rows[i]["total_2l"]) * .45; 

    tbtotal1.Text = total1.ToString();
    tbtotal2.Text = total2.ToString(); 
}
}               
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error in returning selected Values. " +
                    "Processed with error:" + ex.Message);
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably set the text boxes outside the loop. `total` is declared but not used. `total1` and `total2` should be ste to zero before the loop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby)

```
Math.Round(mydoublevalue, 2);
```

In your code

```
tbtotal2.Text = Math.Round(total2, 2).ToString();
```

Comment: @user1483145: also, as you say you are a novice, it may be worth pointing out that .net and therefore c# has a datatype called ``decimal`` that is more accurate with representing decimal numbers than ``double`` is.

Comment: This will not display .00 though, am I right? E.g `26.00` will display as `26`

Answer (score 8):

My answer is pretty late but for those out there like me who want: 
to convert to double/decimal and ***also want the value to always show 2 decimal places (.00)* as** `String`

```
tbtotal2.Text = Math.Round(total2, 2).ToString("#.00");
```

The below means two decimal places at all times.

```
"#.00"
```

The below means two decimal places if there is value.

```
"#.##"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you only want the value rounded for display as a string, you can also use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

```
tbtotal1.Text = String.Format("{0:0.##}", total1);
```

The text "{0:0.##}" describes how you want it to be formatted.  The # indicates that ending zeroes should not be included (eg 1.2 stays the string "1.2"), if you instead do "{0:0.00}", two decimal places are included no matter what, so the double 1.2 would become "1.20".

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this.

```
 tbtotal1.Text = Math.Round(double.Parse(total1.ToString()), 2).ToString();
 tbtotal2.Text = Math.Round(double.Parse(total2.ToString()), 2).ToString();
```